# how to expose page as iframe and isolate them if used in same browser with .net 6

Tags: c#, session, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a web page made with .net 6 integrated with iframe in many other sites.

users can open many of that sites with same browser and i need a way to have session isolated by tab basis and not by the dafault browser basis

I use a custom authentication middleware to invoke corporate single sign on and store some informations in custom claims.

All that claims should be restricted to calling app and not shared with other successive calls

every site call my iframe with a "AppId" parameters

Now when i login users i create claims using AppId as claim type prefix

If user is already logged but has no claims with calling app id i create new claims with that code

But now page can make other internal call and in that call appId is not a parameter so how can i store that information in a way that after first one every other inherits the application?

I read about cookyless session but was removed from  .net for security reason

Many Thanks

EDIT SOME CODE:

many sites have that call to my site

```
<iframe name="ifrRicerca" id="ifrRicerca" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        let form, input;
        form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = "LINK TO MY PAGE";
        form.target = "ifrRicerca";
        form.method = "POST";

        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = "AppCode";
        input.value = "App1";
        form.appendChild(input);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    })();
</script>
```

this is my custom auth middleware

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        
        //escludo la pagina di errore
        if (!context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("rror"))
        {
            try
            {
                // se l'utente corrente non esiste lo imposto
                if (userManager.GetUtenteCorrente().Result is null)
                {
                    context = await userManager.SetUtenteCorrente(context);
                }
                
                else if (!userSettings.ForzaUtente) // se l'utente non è stato impostato significa che non ha i diritti per accedere
                {
                    _logger.Information("Utente non ha i diritti di accedere");
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                    context.Response.Redirect(percorsoErrore + context.Response.StatusCode);
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // se si verifica un errore in spa resituisco errore
                _logger.Information("Authentication middleware - errore nella chiamata a spa");
                _logger.Information(ex.InnerException is null ? ex.Message.ToString() : ex.InnerException.Message.ToString());
                context.Response.StatusCode = 502;
                context.Response.Redirect(percorsoErrore + context.Response.StatusCode);
                return;
            }
        }            
        await _next(context);
    }
```

and here i set claims

```
public async Task<HttpContext> SetUtenteCorrente(HttpContext context)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        utente = GetUserIdFromRequestHeader(context);
        
        var utenteSPA = _UserDataServiceProvider.GetUtente(utente);
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, utenteSPA.Nominativo));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.matricola.ToString(), utenteSPA.Matricola));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.ufficio.ToString(), utenteSPA.Ufficio));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, utenteSPA.Ruolo));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.linguaPredefinita.ToString(), utenteSPA.LinguaDefault.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.linguaCorrente.ToString(), utenteSPA.LinguaCorrente.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.profiloPredefinito.ToString(), utenteSPA.ProfiloDefault));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.profiloCorrente.ToString(), utenteSPA.ProfiloCorrente));
        claims.Add(new Claim(TipoClaim.applicazioneAttiva.ToString(), utenteSPA.ApplicazioneAttiva.ToString()));
        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false };
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "basic");
        context.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity); //senza questa il primo utilizzo dell'utente corrente lo trova vuoto

        await context.SignInAsync(
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
            authProperties);

        return context;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean in different iframework you have different claims and when you authenticate, different iframework has  different claimsIdentity and validate the claims seperately? could you share your codes related which could make it easier for us to understand?

Comment: added some code

Answer (score 0):

There's the SessionStore property in CookieAuthenticationOptions Class,If you want store the ticket in session instead of cookie,you could set as below:
[image]

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookie").AddCookie(x => x.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore());
```

and you need to create MemoryCacheTicketStore class implement the ITicketStore
intereface:

```
public class MemoryCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
    {
        private const string KeyPrefix = "SessionStore";
        private IMemoryCache _cache;
        public MemoryCacheTicketStore()
        {
            _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        }
        Task<AuthenticationTicket> ITicketStore.RetrieveAsync(string key)
        {
            AuthenticationTicket ticket;
            _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ticket);
            return Task.FromResult(ticket);
        }

        Task ITicketStore.RemoveAsync(string key)
        {
            _cache.Remove(key);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
            var key = KeyPrefix + guid.ToString();
             await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
            return key;
        }

        public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
            var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
            if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
            {
                options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
            }
            options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); 

            _cache.Set(key, ticket, options);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
```